# Very Short Papers in Mathematical Journals

Tags: journals

Are there mathematical journals like American Mathematical Monthly that publish very short papers like mathbits?

Mathbits are generally a proof of an old theorem or results.

Comment: do you mean _letters_ like Applied Math. Letters, that publish very short (<6 pages) papers? But they are not exclusively on old results, but on short, concise results.

Comment: I mean the paper can be a new proof of infinitude of primes or pythagorean theorem.

Comment: A new proof in infinitude of primes has (on rare occasions) been published in the *Monthly*. (I think twice, that I know of.)  So you are asking if there are other places for such things?

Comment: @GEdgar Exactly.

Comment: Consider [this one](http://www.ams.org/journals/bull/1966-72-06/S0002-9904-1966-11654-3/S0002-9904-1966-11654-3.pdf), oldie but goodie. Counterexamples may be extremely short.

Comment: The length isn't the key deciding factor, although some do specify length. Length varies considerably by subfield (I consider 20-30 pages normal, but in graph theory it seems to be under 10). A proof of an old theorem will not always be suitable for a research journal, so may fit better in a more magazine-style publication like AMM or the Mathematical Gazette.

Answer (score 1):

New proofs of old theorems are not always very short papers. In the 1960s Norman Levinson published a proof of the prime number theorem that was only six pages long, in contrast to earlier papers that were 50 or 100 pages.

The *American Mathematical Monthly* does publish some short papers of less than one page.

Comment: Thanks for your answer, but I am wondering if there is other journals that publish papers that short than a half page like Mathbits on Monthly.